# Creating a parent child relationship based on dates in SQL

Tags: sql, database, hana

I've got a table that consist of my nodes and parent ids and a date when they are valid from and to for that particular relationship. I want to try and create a parent child relationship using SQL either storing it to another table or directly in a select statement that takes the time dimension into account. I am working on a HANA Database and the Hierarchy functions will be the way to go, but they don't take into account the time dimension. Also HANA doesn't support recursive SQL.

I've tried to depict it in a diagram below. As you can see node 7 moves from 4 --> 5 in the beginning of 2019.

The issue arises when I have a child node i don't have an expiry date on node 8. Then this should move as well, but node 9 that ends in 2016 shouldn't.

```
             1
           /   \
          2     3
         /        \
        4           5
       /              \
      7 Ends(2018)     7 starts(2019)
     / \                \
    8     9 ends(2016)    8
```

So ideally i can get a table where 7 and 8 that transfers gets a new unique ID or at least is clearly represented as only valid to 5 after 2019.

Answer (score 1):

For time dependent hierarchies, the hierarchy generator function [HIERARCHY_TEMPORAL](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4f9859d273254e04af6ab3e9ea3af286/2.0.04/en-US/0be52ba7971740feab5c0a330fced1d1.html) can be used if the pre-conditions are fulfilled. It should be valid too for your case.

Can you explain, why no hierarchy function can be used like you said?

Comment: I want to get the org hierarchy out for all time and drill down on an org unit and see which positions was in it where. The temporal won't work in that case unless I run it on every single entry in my table and copy that over. Ans maybe that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not a SAP person, but what about something like this?

```
Create table daterelation
(
  child numeric,
  parent numeric,
  startdate datetime,
  enddate datetime,
)
```

You could then create a view or function that takes the date and joins on the results.

Comment: That is the output I am looking for. But right now I have a many to many relationship between my nodes and parents and I can't figure out how to address it.

Comment: My suggestion is to populate a table or view with those columns, it will make it easy to create queries that return different items depending on the date.